# How to perform a registration up to verification of account in mvc?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, rest

I don't how to ask this question or even to think of appropriate title for this, but I'll just make it step by step.
I have a project for rest services, and another project for MVC3.
My MVC3 project accesses the rest services via ajax.
i.e: Inside mvc View

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#submit").click(function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'http://localhost:2222/RestService/User/Register',
                type: 'POST',
                contentType: 'application/json',
                data: JSON.stringify({
                    RollNumber: $("#username").val(),
                    Email: $("#email-address").val(),
                    Password: $("#password").val(),
                    Birthday: $("#bday").val()
                }),
                success: function (response) {
                    if (response == true) {
                        window.location.replace('@Url.Action("Index", "Home")');
                    } else {
                        showtooltip('Registration failed.');
                    }
                },
                error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, error) {
                    showtooltip(xhr.status + ': ' + error);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

If a user registration is successful, mvc will automatically send an email.
i.e.: sample of email content:

```
WELCOME TO NEWWEBSITE!

You have successfully registered!
.
.
.
To validate your email address, please go to the link below:

http://localhost:1111/NewWebsite/Auth/Verify?verificationid=3DE4ED727750215957F8A1E4B117C38E7250C33&email=sampleemail%40yahoo.com
```

Then I don't know how to do the next step.
If the user clicked on link to verify his account, how could I get the information from the link?

I have created a Rest service for verification

```
[WebGet(UriTemplate = "RestService/User/Verify?verificationid={verificationid}&email={email}", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
public bool VerifyAccount(string verificationid, string email)
{
    RestLogicClass.RestLogic.UserComponent svc = new RestLogicClass.RestLogic.UserComponent();
    return svc.ValidateEmail(new RestLogicClass.Entities.UserEmail() { EmailAddress = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(email), ValidateKey = verificationid });
}
```

this service can be called by:

```
http://localhost:2222/RestService/User/Verify?verificationid={verificationid}&email={email}
```

If the email has been verified, then it must show to the user the "Verify.cshtml" page from mvc.
this page can be accessed this way:

```
http://localhost:1111/NewWebsite/Auth/Verify
```

Hope you understand my explaination. I'm new to this kind of data processing, so if you have a better idea, please share.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inorder to show the Verify.cshtml. I think you should have an action name

```
public ActionResult Verify(string verificationid, string email)
{
    //// call the service from here and validate 
    //// if valid then return View();
}
```

Also, when you generate the email, generate with this url.